# Script to determine time after a dropdown status is changed (utilizing the edit history)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google sheet-based simple CRM for leads from Facebook ads. When I import leads into the sheet, I assign them the status of Raw in a dropdown column for status. My team then contacts them and updates the status to any one of the 5 different ones available.

Now, I would like to calculate the average number of hours or days before the status of these leads is changed from 'Raw' to any other status.

I am a beginner and would really value assistance here. The script could basically calculate for individual rows and then average them or it could do it all in one go and give the result in a cell.

Here is the link to a sample sheet. In sheet2, is the cell for the result.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nYMGCO7UlH7dHOYzWXpAIMiKQKBUMuLpZov9Jh_blgg/edit?usp=sharing

If the result is specific to the individual Agent, that would be even great.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! This site is for practical, detailed questions about using web applications.  Requesting site users to write a custom script for you is off-topic.  Please take [the tour](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) and also review [What topics can I ask about here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It would make more sense to insert a timestamp in a first column when column `C` is set to `Raw`, and another timestamp in a second column when column `C` is set to to another value. You can then calculate the time difference by simple subtraction. To insert timestamps, use a script. Search this site for the word `timestamp` to find many examples.